# How to use authentication logic to create two different link_to locations (Ruby on Rails & Devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

First post on StackOverflow. :) Am new to Ruby on Rails (and coding in general), and I am struggling the most with understanding documentation. So I am sure this answer is out there somewhere, but if it is, I didn't find/understand it.

I am trying to create two options:

1. Click on logo **before** login- route to **root_path**
2. Click on logo **after** login- route to **alerts_path**

This solution below works, but there must be a better, more tidy and concise way to write it instead of repeating all of that code???

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <%= link_to alerts_path, class: "d-flex flex-row navbar-brand", input_html: {data: {bs_toggle: "offcanvas", bs_target: "#offcanvas"}} do %>
    <%= cl_image_tag("ouicity_logo_j5rhro") %>
    <h2 id="logo" class="ms-3">ouicity</h2>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to root_path, class: "d-flex flex-row navbar-brand", input_html: {data: {bs_toggle: "offcanvas", bs_target: "#offcanvas"}} do %>
    <%= cl_image_tag("ouicity_logo_j5rhro") %>
    <h2 id="logo" class="ms-3">ouicity</h2>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible simple refactor (DRY code) is too just add logic for the url change (using the ternary operator):

```
<%= link_to user_signed_in? ? alerts_path : root_path, class: "d-flex flex-row navbar-brand", input_html: {data: {bs_toggle: "offcanvas", bs_target: "#offcanvas"}} do %>
  <%= cl_image_tag("ouicity_logo_j5rhro") %>
  <h2 id="logo" class="ms-3">ouicity</h2>
<% end %>
```

You can eventually extract this logic to a helper to keep your view simpler:

```rb
def logo_path
  user_signed_in? ? alerts_path : root_path
end
```

```html
<%= link_to logo_path, ...
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly, and I appreciate you sharing both options. :)

Comment: Glad it helped you @AmandaBP and welcome to SO! Please don't forget to accept the answer, it will help future readers reading this thread.

Comment: Thanks, and done! I thought there must be such a function, but I completely overlooked the checkmark.